# Firestore read simulation fails, no highlighted line

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

So, I typically don't have problems writing firestore rules but I'm coming up short on why this simulation fails.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

If you don't want to follow the image link:

Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database} {
    match /server_credentials/{document = **} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /users/{user_uid} {
        allow read, write;
        match /signatures/{sig_id} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid != null  && resource.data.access == "public";
          allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user_uid;
        }
        match /identity/{credential} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user_uid;
        }
    }
    match /signatures/{sig_id} {
        allow read, list;
        allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Auth details:
Google as provider and `foo` as the uid.

I'm testing a simple read to `users/foo`

Any help would be quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
match /databases/{database} {
```

It should be this:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
```

This mistake is causing none of your rules to apply at all, and all access is being rejected by default.